# setInterval running more times than intended?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, setinterval, mousemove

I have an application written in node.js using socket.io. The main event loop looks like this:

```
io.on("connect", function(CLIENT) {
    //Run this code when a client connects
    SERVER.connectPlayer(CLIENT);
    
    //Recieve input from client
    SERVER.handleInput(CLIENT);
    
    //Run this code when a client disconnects
    CLIENT.on("disconnect", function() {
        SERVER.disconnectPlayer(CLIENT);
    });
});

function main() {
    SERVER.update();
}

setInterval(main, SERVER.tickRate);
```

This works fine, but I'm having an issue with `SERVER.handleInput`:

```
//Recieve input from the client
Server.prototype.handleInput = function(client) {
    client.on("sendKey", function(data) {
        client.player.handleKey(data.key, data.pressed);
    });
    
    client.on("sendMouse", function(data) {
        client.player.mouse_x = data.x;
        client.player.mouse_y = data.y;
    });
}
```

Both of these work fine, but the second method `client.on("sendMouse")` triggers my `main()` loop above whenever it is run. I've tried commenting out the body of `sendMouse` but that doesn't change anything.

This method is being triggered by the client whenever the user moves the mouse. This is the code I'm using:

```
//Handles input on the client and sends it to the server
Game.prototype.bindKeys = function() {
    var game = this;
    this.input = {};
    
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        game.mouseMove(event);
    }, false);
}

Game.prototype.mouseMove = function(event) {
    this.setMousePos(event);
    client.emit("sendMouse", this.mouse);
}
```

`setMousePos` just figures out the current position of the cursor and sets it so that the client knows what coordinates to send back to the server. If I remove `sendMouse` on the client the game runs perfectly but otherwise my main setInterval loop is being run additionally every time `sendMouse` triggers.

I have no idea what would cause this. The keyboard input works perfectly fine. I'd greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: Where is main getting called? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: main() gets called at the bottom of my app.js which is the server logic. It runs many more times than it should whenever I'm moving the mouse. It should only be running once every `SERVER.tickRate` ticks as I've specified.

Comment: It's hard to debug without seeing the full code. Are you sure your SERVER.tickRate is immutable? Could that even emitter some how be resetting the tick rate?

Comment: If I replace it with `setInterval(main, 10);` the issue persists. It runs every 10 miliseconds but additionally when the mouse is being moved. Interestingly though, I found that if I comment out the entire `setMouse` code on the server side, the issue persists. So the problem seems to be with the `client.emit` code on the client, which makes very little sense to me.

Comment: Why would you need main() to be called at the bottom of the app.js file if you're already polling with main() in setInterval? Could it be that socket.io runs through the script again when your event handler gets called?

Comment: It's only being called through setInterval, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I console logged the main function and found it definitely runs more times while that `client.emit` code is being triggered. I have no idea what the connection is.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. I think the key to solving your problem is to look at the context the setInterval call is in. It seems it would be inside another function that re-calls it when an event is emitted.

Comment: That seems like it would be the issue but it doesn't trigger when my keyboard code triggers. I omitted the code from the above post to make it less lengthy but it does pretty much the same thing which led me to believe it's an issue with mousemove.